# How to download "en_core_web_sm" model at runtime in spacy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nlp, spacy, serverless-framework

I am working on writing a lambda function which depends on Spacy's "en_core_web_sm" model. Due to limitation of AWS Lambda, I need to find a mechanism which allows me to download the model at runtime (I can afford to increase the lambda timeout).

**Note:** I can't use EFS at the moment due to some requirement restriction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this.

```
from spacy.cli import download

download("en_core_web_sm")
```

See [the source](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/4da2af4e0e522496f9418ae3721262f7e8254050/spacy/cli/download.py#L38).